# Cut & paste broken for IOS

Tags: bug, ios-app

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,2)
- OS Version: Version 11.1.1 (Build 15B150)

I was editing a comment, but the time limit expired.  I selected and cut the text from the edit window before canceling, but was unable to paste it into a new comment.

Similarly, I decided that already saved comment text would be better in an answer.  I tapped the comment and tapped ‘copy.’  The app told me it was copied.  Edited a comment, but then paste did nothing.

Comment: Also unable to paste into answers after the "copy" announced that it was successful.